# How do I get the maximum value(s) in a (seaborn) JointKDE plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

How do I get the maximum value(s) in a (seaborn) JointKDE plot? Like the image below. I want to get the blue points coordinate like (121.53,31.29) and (121.58,31.27)。

Thanks a lot!
[image: 0]

Comment: Pure from the seaborn plot doesn't seem very feasible nor accurate.  [How to find Local maxima in Kernel Density Estimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198020/how-to-find-local-maxima-in-kernel-density-estimation) describes methods to find local maxima from an n-dimensional kde.